# DataTable's DataCell Background Color

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the background color of a DataCell in DataTable. i.e

```
DataRow(cells: [
  DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
  DataCell(Container(
    child: Text(i[1].text),
    color: customTheme.colors.bgColor,
  )),
  DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
  DataCell(FlutterLogo()),
]),
```

But the above code change a small portion of the DataCell (just the background color of
text) because the container has the size of the text.
How can I change the full DataCell background color?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SizedBox.expand` to make this happen.

If you navigate to the DataCell source, you will find it's using `SizedBox.shrink()` as a default component. So, I got the idea from it.

You can set `columnSpacing: 0` in `DataTable` definition. But this will lead unnecessary compact no space between cell edges. So you can use `Padding` or `Container` widget to add padding arround.

Here I use `Align` component to middle-center the text.

```
DataCell(
    // Use SizedBox.expand to fill the cell
    SizedBox.expand(

        // Use container to fill the background color
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
            color: Colors.yellow,
 
            // Align text to middle
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "Sample Text",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

dartpad example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=ea0f688aec73edcc30cfb6028fb34df1

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer flutter [`DataTable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

```
DataTable(
  headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
    (states) => Colors.blue,
  ),//for heading row color
  columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(
        'Name',
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      ),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(
        'Age',
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      ),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(
        'Role',
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      ),
    ),
  ],
  rows: <DataRow>[
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
        DataCell(Text('19')),
        DataCell(Text('Student')),
      ],
    ),
    DataRow(
      color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),//for data row color
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('William')),
        DataCell(Text('27')),
        DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. You are changing a Row color but I am looking for changing a single Cell color in a Row or Column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different color for each column you can use, gradient property of the DataTable, just put necessary stops wherever needed, also Color list should be of same length as stop.

Here's the example

```
return DataTable(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Colors.green, Color(0xffadd8e6)],
                          stops: [0.4,0.4],
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight),
                    ),
                    columns: const [
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          'Field',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Value')),
                    ],
                    rows: tv.map((tableValue) {
                      return DataRow(
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(Text(tableValue.title)),
                          DataCell(Text(tableValue.value)),
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
```

[image]